# Django - ensure there is only one ACTIVE product per user

Tags: python, django, django-models

Having this model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(...)

    STATUS_ACTIVE = 'active'
    STATUS_CANCELLED = 'cancelled'
    STATUS_DRAFT = 'draft'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_ACTIVE,'Active'),
        ...
    )
    status = models.CharField(..., choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make `User` model having only one product that is `ACTIVE`. `User` is allowed to have any number of `CANCELLED` and `DRAFT` products, but only one can be `ACTIVE`.

I'm thinking about `CheckConstraint` but I can't figure out such query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a `UniqueConstraint`, but under the condition that `status` is active:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(…)

    STATUS_ACTIVE = 'active'
    STATUS_CANCELLED = 'cancelled'
    STATUS_DRAFT = 'draft'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_ACTIVE,'Active'),
        …
    )
    status = models.CharField(…, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['user'],
                condition=Q(status=STATUS_ACTIVE),
                name='one_user_per_active_product'
            )
        ]
```

The [**`condition=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#condition) was only introduced since [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0), and furthermore not all databases per se enforce such constraints.